# Mapping Home Directories With Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script That creates Users in Active Directory And I wanted to add a feature that maps a network drive to A shared Folder.

When I check my AD User I saw that the Network Drive was mapped in the profile tab

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Credential prod\administrator
do
{
clear
# ad user creation tool
Write-Host
'
-------------------------------------------------------------
AD User Creation tool
-------------------------------------------------------------
'
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
try
{
New-ADOrganizationalUnit 'DC=Prod,DC=Ido,DC=Local' -ErrorAction Stop -Credential $creds
}
Catch
{
Write-Host 'Temp OU Has Been Created'
}
$OU = 'OU=tempOU,DC=Prod,DC=Ido,DC=Local'
$Firstname = Read-Host 'Enter The First Name'
$lastname = Read-Host 'Enter the last name'
$Username = $Firstname + $lastname[0]
$password = Read-Host 'Enter a Password' -AsSecureString
New-ADUser -Name "$Firstname $lastname" -GivenName $Firstname -Surname $lastname -SamAccountName $Username -AccountPassword $password -Enabled $true -Credential $creds
$Idenity = Get-ADUser $Username | select -Property DistinguishedName
Move-ADObject -Identity $Idenity.DistinguishedName -TargetPath $OU -PassThru -Credential $creds
$DriveLatter = 'h'
$HomeDirPath = '\\dc01\Data\HomeDIrectories\' + $username
# Define the username and UNC path of the home directory
#Set the home directory for the user
Set-ADUser -Identity $username -HomeDrive 'h' -HomeDirectory $HomeDirPath -Credential $creds
pause
}
while (1 -eq 1 )
```

But When I login into the user To check if The Network Drive was mapped, It Didn't work

I tried to logoff and logon From The user Multipletimes but to no avail

But When I tried to change Home Folder manualy, it Suddenly Worked

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Did you change the environmental variable HomePath?

Comment: The driveletter needs to be in uppercase and followed by a colon, so `H:`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-homedrive)